# Help me understanding what actually i counted with inclusion-exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I tried to solve following task:

> Count number of $8$-permutations from $2$ letters $A$, $2$ letters $B$, $2$ letters $C$ and $2$ letters $D$ where **exactly one** pair of same letters are adjacent in resulting permutation

My solution is straightforward: let $A_i$ be the number of permutations with at least $i$ pairs of same letters adjacent, then our solution will be $A_1 - A_2 + A_3 - A_4$
$$A_1=\binom{4}{1}\times 7 \times 1! \times \frac{6!}{2^3}$$
$$A_2=\binom{4}{2}\times 15 \times 2! \times \frac{4!}{2^2}$$
$$A_3=\binom{4}{3}\times 10 \times 3! \times \frac{2!}{2^1}$$
$$A_4=\binom{4}{4}\times 1 \times 4! \times \frac{0!}{2^0}$$
My logic is following: first take $i$ pairs of same letters that for sure gonna be adjacent, then count number of possibilities to place those pairs in permutation (i used recurrence relation $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+f(n-2,k-1)$ to count number of ways to put $k$ $2$-blocks in $n$-block line), then we can permute those pairs $i!$ times, lastly we permute rest of the letters in $\frac{(8-2i)!}{2^{4-i}}$ ways.

Result of this is $1656$ and correct result (according to my computer program) is $984$, so it seems i'm hugely overcounting something, but i have no idea what.

I'd appreciate some help on this.

Comment: In your expression for $A_2$, the factor 7 is for 7 possible positions of the first of a pair of letters, and 5 for remaining 5 positions for the first letter of a second pair? That doesn't work. For exampe, if one pair occupies positions 2 and 3, where can the second pair go?

Comment: @ChristianSievers you are right! I came up with reccurence: 
$f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+f(n-2,k-1)$ and it would be number of ways i can put $k$ $2$-blocks in $n$-block line. It gave me numbers like:
$f(8,1)=7$, $f(8,2)=15$, $f(8,3)=10$, $f(8,4)=1$
And if i plug those numbers instead of $7$, $7*5$, $7*5*3$, $1$ then i get result $1656$
Link to whole calculation can be found here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(C(4,1)+*+7+*+6!%2F2%5E3)+-+(C(4,2)+*+2+*+15+*+3!)+%2B+(C(4,3)+*+3!+*+10)+-+4!

Comment: So i'm still very overcounting something

Comment: Also i updated result in the question.

Comment: You are counting the number of arrangements in which *at least* one pair identical letters are adjacent.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig wouldn't that be just $A_1$?

Comment: No.  I am writing a solution, but it will take some time before it is ready.

Comment: I tried distributing 2-blocks, but ended having distinguished 2-blocks. For example there can be an explicitblock at position (1,2), or at position (3,4), and these cases are not disjoint! We'd have to use inclusion-exclusion again to get that right.

Comment: I think you should use sets $A_i$ with $1\le i\le 7$ corresponding to having repeated letters at position $i$ and $i+1$. That would allow to count words with no pair of adjacent same letters, but exactly one seems a bit more difficult. BTW, I agree with your computer result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $7!/2^3=630$ permutations with a pair of adjacent letters A.

There are $6!/2^2=180$ permutations with a pair of adjacent letters A and a pair of adjacent letters B. Same for A and C, and for A and D.

There are $5!/2=60$ permutations with a pair of adjacent letters A and a pair of adjacent letters B and a pair of adjacent letters C. Same for A and B and D, and for A and C and D.

There are $4!=24$ permutations where all letters occur as adjacent pair.

So there are $630-3\times 180+3\times 60-24=246$ permutations that have a pair of adjacent letters A and no other adjacent pair of letters.

So there are $4\times 246=984$ permutations that have exactly one pair of adjacent letters.

Comment: Your explaination is extremly clear, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are counting the number of arrangements in which *at least* one pair of adjacent letters is adjacent.

As you found, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of arrangements that include at least one double letter is 
$$\binom{4}{1}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!} - \binom{4}{2}\frac{6!}{2!2!} + \binom{4}{3}\frac{5!}{2!} - \binom{4}{4}4!$$
However, we want the number of arrangements in which exactly one double letter occurs.  When we count arrangements in which a double letter occurs, we count each arrangement in which two double letters occur twice, each arrangement in which three double letters occur three times, and each arrangement in which four double letters occur four times. Since we do not wish to count these arrangements at all, the number of arrangements in which exactly one double letter occurs is 
$$\binom{4}{1}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!} - 2\binom{4}{2}\frac{6!}{2!2!} + 3\binom{4}{3}\frac{5!}{2!} - 4\binom{4}{4}4!$$
When we made our initial count of $$\binom{4}{1}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!}$$ we chose a double letter, then arranged the seven objects (the double letter and the three pairs of single letters).  In doing so, we counted each arrangement with two double letters twice.  For instance, we counted arrangements with a double A and a double B once when we chose the double A and arranged the remaining letters once when we chose the double B and arranged the remaining letters.  By similar argument, we counted each arrangement with three double letters three times and each arrangement with four double letters four times, once for each of the ways we could have chosen one of those double letters as our double letter in the initial count.

Comment: Your formula gives 2520 as the number of permutations with at least one double letter, but there are only 1656. You are counting the number of ways to write permutations and underline one double letter. (Still your result is correct - fascinating!)

Comment: @ChristianSievers The number of permutations with at least one double letter is $$\binom{4}{1}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!} - \binom{4}{2}\frac{6!}{2!2!} + \binom{4}{3}\frac{5!}{2!} - \binom{4}{4}4! = 1656$$

Comment: In the begining you seem to claim that it is just the first term. I saw you explained more later. You're also overcounting the number of permutations with two and with three double letters, but in the end it all works out.

Comment: I'm pretty stunned by this idea of underlining one double letter, just like @ChristianSievers said.

Comment: I decided to accept Christian's answer, cause it's shorter, too bad i can't accept them both, cause they are really great.

Comment: @ChristianSievers  The way I worded my initial solution was sloppy.  Normally, when we apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, we wish to exclude something that occurs at least once.  In this case, the number of arrangements in which no double letter occurs is $$\frac{8!}{2!2!2!2!} - \left[\frac{4}{1}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!} - \binom{4}{2}\frac{6!}{2!2!} + \frac{4}{3}\frac{5!}{2!2!} - \binom{4}{4}4!\right]$$ where the expression in the brackets counts those arrangements that include *at least* one double letter.  In this case, we wish to count those arrangements with *exactly* one double letter.

Comment: @ChristianSievers  To count arrangements with exactly one double letter, we must exclude those arrangements in which more than one double letter occurs, which forces us to count how many times we initially counted each such arrangement when we first chose a double letter, then arranged the remaining letters.  The factors of $2$, $3$, and $4$ represent, respectively, the number of times we counted arrangements with two, three, and four double letters in our initial count.

Comment: $4\times 7!/2^3$ is the sum of the sizes of the sets of perms that have double letter $X$, for $X\in\{A,B,C,D\}$. The next term is the sum of the sizes of all the sets of perms that have two fixed double letters, and so on. That is overcounting in exactly the way the principle of inclusion and exclusion fixes.